# Codename one handling image memory size?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, crash, codenameone

My Senario is the following , I have a form where I need the user to attach images that he takes from the camera [count vary depending on forms -I have many cases- ]
the application display an alert of no available memory [ on some devices , I have seen it on (Samsung A5 [2015 release] , Xiaomi Note 4)

```
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError - Failed to allocate a 16894 byte allocation with 11344 free bytes and 11KB until OOM
```

and some times on loading the map

```
Process: com.x.y, PID: 17227
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 65548 byte allocation with 14824 free bytes and 10KB until OOM
    at com.android.okhttp.okio.Segment.<init>(Segment.java:62)
    at com.android.okhttp.okio.SegmentPool.take(SegmentPool.java:46)
    at com.android.okhttp.okio.Buffer.writableSegment(Buffer.java:1114)
    at com.android.okhttp.okio.Buffer.write(Buffer.java:940)
    at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSink$1.write(RealBufferedSink.java:197)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:107)
    at java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(FilterOutputStream.java:97)
    at ez.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@13280047@13.2.80 (040308-211705629):15)
    at ez.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@13280047@13.2.80 (040308-211705629):83)
    at ep.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@13280047@13.2.80 (040308-211705629):2)
    at eo.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@13280047@13.2.80 (040308-211705629):4)
    at eq.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@13280047@13.2.80 (040308-211705629):55)
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.drd.ap.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@13280047@13.2.80 (040308-211705629):11)
    at dx.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@13280047@13.2.80 (040308-211705629):17)
    at dx.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@13280047@13.2.80 (040308-211705629):65)
```

the code that is used to capture and take the image and store it array of images

```
String filePath = Capture.capturePhoto();
applicationAttachment[index] = temp;    
applicationAttachment[index].setImageName(labelName.substring(0, labelName.length()-"Label".length()));
```

My question here , how can I handle the image based on available memory if that is possible ??

Comment: You have a memory leak. You ran out of memory completely and can't allocate `65548` bytes. (64kb). Generally camera images are very large especially for the high mega-pixel range so if you're loading these images into RAM you can quickly run out of it

Comment: @ShaiAlmog , I also noticed that {Capture.capturePhoto();} don't create an image file to get back to in case I want to load it again

Comment: It returns a temporary image

Comment: @ShaiAlmog how can I make it permanent and reside in the gallery so I could choose to take it again instead of capturing it again

Comment: Having a permanent file won't change the fact that you are loading stuff into RAM which is a different resource (and the cause of your memory leak). You can pick an image from the gallery using the gallery picker. You can also copy the file from the temporary result to a permanent place in your application directory.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog , I tried many codes that copy the file but it didn't work , more importantly , how can I put the image in the gallery instead of the application directory [ or if it is in the application directory it will show up in the gallery ??]

Comment: By default we don't show the captured images in the gallery since this might not be what people want. If you want deeper control over the camera you can use the low level camera cn1lib https://www.codenameone.com/blog/camerakit-low-level-camera-api.html